# Run command(s) after sshing into device - Python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I would like to ssh into a device and then run commands. Current I am able to ssh into the device but as soon as I try and write another command, it appears to exit from the session/shell and write the command to my previous shell/terminal. I have something that connects fine, currently:

```
def run_ssh():
  p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','<address>'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, when i add something like:

```
 subprocess.stdin.write('pwd')
```

It executes this command from my original terminal I'm 'sshing' from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the paramiko library, not subprocess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code from your script. Ideally, you'd show a complete simple script which someone could run to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you're not working on a terminal, SSH won't allocate you a pseudo-terminal on the other side. You should see some error like

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

when running `subprocess` as you did. You can force a terminal on the other side with `-tt`, but this can have very weird results, depending on what your `rc` file is doing on the other side. Another option is to directly run the shell you want to work in, and that way you can start it without sourcing the `rc` file. Here for example I use the more basic Dash to avoid all kind's of things that happen to commands in my normal Bash shell workflowm, though you could use `/bin/bash --norc --noprofile`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-p','2022','localhost','/bin/dash'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write(b'echo hello world\n')
>>> p.stdin.flush()

>>> for line in p.stdout: print(line)
...
b'hello world\n'
```

Note that as soon as you read `stdout`, you will hang, since you connect to the Pipe. Note also flushing `stdin` is a must to be sure your commands were actually executed.